# Errors: multiple definition and first defined here

Tags: c, makefile

I have tried to include pretty much every combination of headers. Trying to compile the object files by using:

```
gcc database.c -c
gcc database.o user_interface.c -o database
```

The result is:

```
/tmp/ccWfp2tS.o: In function `addRecord':
user_interface.c:(.text+0x4b9): multiple definition of `addRecord'
database.o:database.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccWfp2tS.o: In function `printAllRecords':
user_interface.c:(.text+0x54a): multiple definition of `printAllRecords'
database.o:database.c:(.text+0x1a): first defined here
/tmp/ccWfp2tS.o: In function `findRecord':
user_interface.c:(.text+0x590): multiple definition of `findRecord'
database.o:database.c:(.text+0x24): first defined here
/tmp/ccWfp2tS.o: In function `deleteRecord':
user_interface.c:(.text+0x5ed): multiple definition of `deleteRecord'
database.o:database.c:(.text+0x36): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

user_interface.c

```
#include "record.h"

int debugmode; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
    // my code here
}
    // other functions: AddRecord, printallRecords,...
```

database.h

```
#include "record.h"

int addRecord (struct record **, int, char [ ],char [ ]);
void printAllRecords(struct record *);
int findRecord (struct record *, int);
int deleteRecord(struct record **, int);
```

database.c

```
#include "database.h"

extern int debugmode; 

int addRecord(struct record ** start, int account, char name[], char address[])
{
    /*my code here*/
    return 0;
}
/*other functions...*/
```

record.h

```
struct record
{
    int                accountno;
    char               name[25];
    char               address[80];
    struct record*     next;
};
```

Comment: Based on the comment in user_interface.c it sounds like you have the same functions defined in both files. It would help to see all of the files, not just snippets you think are relevant.

Comment: `// other functions: AddRecord, printallRecords,...` Ask yourself why those are in both `user_interface.c` and `database.c`. You literally provided two implementations of the *same* functions in two different source files, and the linker is telling you precisely that when trying to fix up identifiers.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have the same functions in database.c and user_interface.c

Comment: @WhozCraig that's the problem then!

Comment: @JoanaF. Exactly. And that is entirely the problem. From the looks of your code, user_interface.c should include record.h and database.h for type declarations, and the implementation of those db-functions should be in database.c *only*. Chances are you also need include-guard fenceposts in your headers, btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig I only left the functions on the database.c (required). However, I call the functions in database.c and get this error from the compiler:  undefined reference to 'some function'

Comment: You build commands are also whacked. You should use `gcc -c -o database.o database.c` for the database object code, `gcc-c -o user_inteface.o user_interface.c` for the ui object code, and finally `gcc -o database user_interface.o database.o` for the final link. That, assuming you did everything else correctly.

Comment: If `user_interface.c` is calling functions declared in `database.h`, then it needs to `#include "database.h"`

Comment: @MadScientist user_interface.c includes #include "database.c" (because I call functions in database.c), and database.c includes "record.h" and include "database.h". But I am getting error as well. Error: multiple definitions of 'some' function

Comment: You should never, ever include a .c file from another .c file.  That will always give you duplicate definitions, because you have one definition in the c file (database.c) then another definition in the other c file (user_interface.c) because you included the first one.  You only ever include header files.  (when I say "never ever" there are actually times which it might be useful but you will have many months/years programming under your belt before you run into them).

Comment: @MadScientist if I do not include database.c in user_interface.c it gives me errors. Actually even more errors.

Comment: Well, you'll have to solve those errors.  But the solution is not to include the source file.  It turns out that having fewer errors doesn't necessarily mean you're moving in the right direction :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be having a lot of troubles because you're down in the weeds, throwing things at the wall.  But it's not really that hard if you step back and look at it from a higher level.

The concept of interest here are *declarations* vs. *definitions*.  It's unfortunate they have such similar names: it's easy to get them confused.

Think of a *definition* like your house, and a *declaration* like the address of your house.  You only have one of your house, but you can hand out your address to lots of different people.  Your address tells people how to get to your house, but it isn't actually your house.

Similarly in C, a *definition* of a function is the actual implementation of the function, and the *declaration* of the function describes how to call the function.

A declaration looks like this:

```
void printAllRecords(struct record *);
```

(note, no body of the function, just the way it's called) and a definition looks like:

```
void printAllRecords(struct record *record)
{
    ...do some stuff...
}
```

(note, now you have the body of the function)

You normally put the *declaration* in a header file.  Then anyone who wants to call your function will `#include` that header file, so that they know the right way to call it.

But you don't want to `#include` the *definition* of a function (for example, by `#include`ing the source file) because that would mean you have two implementations of the same function, and that's not possible just like there can't be two of your house.

So, in short:

- Put definitions of functions into source files
- Put declarations of functions into header files
- You should `#include` the header file containing the declaration in the source file containing the definition, so the compiler will complain if they don't match
- And finally, if you want to call the function from some other source file, `#include` the header file containing the declaration in that source file too

In your case, all the functions *defined* in `database.c` should have *declarations* in `database.h`, then any other source file (like `user_interface.c`) should `#include "database.h"` to see those declarations.

Comment: Data structures don't have "implementations" like functions, so they are usually declared and defined at the same time, inside a header file.  Then any source or header file that needs that data structure should include that header file.

Comment: Upvote for the analogy of house vs address